# Swift generics and subscript - value is not identical to K

Tags: generics, swift, subscript

I'm getting a compile error because compiler thinks the "key" in my tuple is not the same type as the generic array. Any idea why?

```
class MyClass <K: Hashable, V> {

   let keys = [K]()

   subscript(index: Int) -> (key: K, value: V) {
      set(newValue) {
         // also tried newValue.key!
         keys[index] = newValue.key
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: BTW, why do you have `return` statement in setter? It should give you a compile error as well?

Comment: @Keenle Sorry that was a typo in my question, the actual code is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to set value of an array `keys` while it is declared as immutable array. `keys` array should be declared as:

```
var keys = [K]() // var declaration makes it mutable
```

Comment: Awesome that was it. Made the array final instead of using let